# How do I assign dollar value to different life activities like vacation, health so I can prioritize them

Tags: budget

Most of us think in terms of what's profitable to use and what's not. It's easy to apply to business related expenses because you know how much money it will bring you back.

But there are other things like:

1. Health
2. Vacations
3. Comfy home

While health is obvious, I would argue that we need vacations as well as a comfy house (rather than cheapest) to be more productive and happier in general. So, I struggle with prioritizing them. Like how much of the budget I should spend on health? How many vacations I should take?

It's just not me, I've noticed many peoples who chase wealth during their whole life, and later regret neglecting on their health. Some just spend it all, and later are poor.

I understand it depends upon me, but let's say I am not good at prioritizing stuff and I am one of the person who chases wealth all his life, only to regret it later. Personally, I am spending 40% of my salary (20% tax + 20% expense) and saving 60%. But I recently started my first job around 6 months ago, so I don't have any wealth or much of emergency funds.

So, are their some guides or articles, or general feedback, which I should consider to make the decision correctly.

Comment: Isn't the reason that there a trillions of life-work-balance books/coaches/youtube channels/magazine articels/people that pretend to have the answer to that question /seminars/... the fact that there is no simple answer to this question?

Comment: I suggest you throw some dice. It will work as well as any other method, it is easier and faster than most, and if you do not like the result you can blame the dice (or reroll)

Comment: Part of the problem is assuming that such valuations *can* be made.

Comment: I got a perfectly reasonable answer to my question today. Of course there is no answer that can tell the exact amount number of vacations days I must take, but the answer posted today served as a good guide to what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to somewhat quantify personal preferences, which seem like an impossible task.

However one thing you could consider, if you need to monetize it somehow, is to think what the end goal is? Is the end-goal happiness, wealth, economic freedom or something completely different?

Say the end goal is happiness; one way to monetize that is to take a look at the happiest nations and see what they do. Some of the happiest countries are Scandinavian countries; and what do they offer that seem to make them more happy than everybody else?
Most of them have 5 weeks of paid holidays per year, free healthcare and a social welfare system. Things that can be “purchased” in almost every country.
Also they spend somewhere between 30-40% of their disposable income on housing (more in capital areas)

So if we assume this to be the determining premises; how much does 5 weeks of vacation cost (ie 5 weeks of time-off, not including the actual cost of a holiday trip)? That costs roughly 10% of a yearly salary (5 / 52).

Add to that a full healthcare insurance and a monthly savings that you could live off for say 6 months or so.

This is by no means perfect, or necessarily a correct premise; but at least it gives you some way to quantify how much you need to spend, in order to obtain the same lifestyle as the worlds happiest nations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helpful. I think all of us just want to be happy at the end of the day.

Comment: I have found that the **time** I spend on vacation is IMHO usually "worth" more than the **money** I spend ON it. Which means, I don't plan for vacation that costs on average more per day than what I would have earned were I at work that period: I'd rather have a cheaper, but longer vacation. This also neatly scales with income.

Comment: @StianYttervik But that's also a personal preference. Other people might rather want two weeks of adventure and/or luxury rather than four weeks of sitting on the couch watching Netflix.

Comment: @StianYttervik that is only possible if you actually get paid time off; if you have to pay for the days yourself, by getting a salary reduction, each day already costs at least the same as you would be earning. On top of that you have the actual cost of doing something (ie traveling expenses, food, etc)

Answer (score 1):

For most people, commitments take up so much time that calculation isn’t needed. Whatever time the work can spare goes into family, friends, hobbies / solitude, and the like.

However, if you have the luxury of wealth, a temperament tending towards indecision and a preference for formulae, you could do the following.

1. Determine how you will measure your utility: money, satisfaction, etc. Call this measure *m*. We will use the convention that you prefer higher *m*.
2. Work out a formula *m = f(t)* given contiguous time without rest (or food, or vacations, or family time, or time with friends, etc). You will usually find diminishing returns at some point, so for small time periods *t*, *f(t)* will increase at a possibly accelerating rate, then the increase will slow. Given a long enough time, you might even find that *f(t+1) < f(t)*.
3. Work out the effect of rest / socialising / etc on your productivity. You might have *m = 0* while you’re resting, though having passive investments might allow a nonzero *m*. However, when you get back to work, your *f(t)* will likely restart higher than before the rest. Diminishing returns also applies here, so if the vacation is too long, you might need time to re-hone your skills.
4. Play around with the variables, especially how long and how often you rest, until you hit an optimal value for the modified function, given suitably large *t*.

After trying this for awhile, you’ll probably look for something simpler to work with, such as setting your priorities by fiat rather than trying to determine the best ‘priorities’ to optimise your utility.